# Dynamically change Rails variable with a jQuery menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, calendar

I am trying to create an app that involves users creating several calendars. After they have added their calendars, they will select which one they want to view/ edit from a dropdown menu. After they select this calendar, its content will be shown underneath.

Here's the code I have for creating the calendar form, which does not seem to do anything:

```
= semantic_form_for calendar do |f|
    = f.collection_select :is_active,  @business.calendars.all, :id, :summary
    = f.submit
```

My idea is to toggle the 'is_active' parameter, so that if it is true, that will be the calendar that is displayed.

I am looking at some jQuery solutions.

Here's a pic of what I have so far:

[image]